# Proportionally scaling a container with absolute positioned elements so it fits into viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As source material, I got a carefully composed layout, consisting of a div container (960x540) with absolutely positioned elements:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Portraits */
[class*="portrait-"] {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 102px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.portrait-01 {
    top: 36px;
    left: 536px;
}

.portrait-02 {
    top: 58px;
    left: 648px;
}

.portrait-03 {
    top: 82px;
    left: 760px;
}

.portrait-04 {
    top: 152px;
    left: 794px;
}

.portrait-05 {
    top: 222px;
    left: 810px;
}

.portrait-06 {
    top: 292px;
    left: 794px;
}

.portrait-07 {
    top: 362px;
    left: 760px;
}

.portrait-08 {
    top: 386px;
    left: 648px;
}

.portrait-09 {
    top: 408px;
    left: 536px;
}

.portrait-10 {
    top: 419px;
    left: 424px;
}

.portrait-11 {
    top: 408px;
    left: 312px;
}

.portrait-12 {
    top: 386px;
    left: 200px;
}

.portrait-13 {
    top: 362px;
    left: 88px;
}

.portrait-14 {
    top: 292px;
    left: 54px;
}

.portrait-15 {
    top: 222px;
    left: 38px;
}

.portrait-16 {
    top: 152px;
    left: 54px;
}

.portrait-17 {
    top: 82px;
    left: 88px;
}

.portrait-18 {
    top: 58px;
    left: 200px;
}

.portrait-19 {
    top: 36px;
    left: 312px;
}

.portrait-20 {
    top: 25px;
    left: 424px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="portrait-01">P-01</div>
  <div class="portrait-02">P-02</div>
  <div class="portrait-03">P-03</div>
  <div class="portrait-04">P-04</div>
  <div class="portrait-05">P-05</div>
  <div class="portrait-06">P-06</div>
  <div class="portrait-07">P-07</div>
  <div class="portrait-08">P-08</div>
  <div class="portrait-09">P-09</div>
  <div class="portrait-10">P-10</div>
  <div class="portrait-11">P-11</div>
  <div class="portrait-12">P-12</div>
  <div class="portrait-13">P-13</div>
  <div class="portrait-14">P-14</div>
  <div class="portrait-15">P-15</div>
  <div class="portrait-16">P-16</div>
  <div class="portrait-17">P-17</div>
  <div class="portrait-18">P-18</div>
  <div class="portrait-19">P-19</div>
  <div class="portrait-20">P-20</div>
</div>
```

How can I rewrite code, so the container fills all available space in viewport by scaling all of its children while keeping their original proportions?

A js/jQuery solution would be okay as well as pure HTML/CSS.

[image]

Comment: instead of `px` I would write the whole code using `vmin` and it's done.

Comment: seems to be a good direction, but just replacing px by `vmin` isn't enough, elements get way too large.

Comment: by replace, I didn't meant a "string replace". You need to recalculate all the values using `vmin` not simply replace `px` with `vmin` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As suggested by @TemaniAfif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474047/proportionally-scaling-a-container-with-absolute-positioned-elements-so-it-fits#comment136582453_77474047),

> instead of `px` I would write the whole code using `vmin` and it's done.

and

> **(We)** need to recalculate all the values using `vmin` not simply replace `px` with `vmin` in your code

here's the code:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 172vmin;
  height: 92vmin;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

[class*="portrait-"] {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 18vmin;
  height: 11vmin;
  font-size: 6.5vmin;
  text-align: center;
}

.portrait-01 {
  top: 6vmin;
  left: 96vmin;
}

.portrait-02 {
  top: 9vmin;
  left: 116vmin;
}

.portrait-03 {
  top: 14vmin;
  left: 136vmin;
}

.portrait-04 {
  top: 27vmin;
  left: 142vmin;
}

.portrait-05 {
  top: 39.5vmin;
  left: 145vmin;
}

.portrait-06 {
  top: 52vmin;
  left: 142vmin;
}

.portrait-07 {
  top: 66vmin;
  left: 136vmin;
}

.portrait-08 {
  top: 71vmin;
  left: 116vmin;
}

.portrait-09 {
  top: 73vmin;
  left: 96vmin;
}

.portrait-10 {
  top: 75.5vmin;
  left: 76vmin;
}

.portrait-11 {
  top: 73vmin;
  left: 56vmin;
}

.portrait-12 {
  top: 71vmin;
  left: 36vmin;
}

.portrait-13 {
  top: 66vmin;
  left: 15.7vmin;
}

.portrait-14 {
  top: 53vmin;
  left: 10vmin;
}

.portrait-15 {
  top: 40vmin;
  left: 7vmin;
}

.portrait-16 {
  top: 27vmin;
  left: 10vmin;
}

.portrait-17 {
  top: 14vmin;
  left: 15vmin;
}

.portrait-18 {
  top: 8vmin;
  left: 35vmin;
}

.portrait-19 {
  top: 6vmin;
  left: 55vmin;
}

.portrait-20 {
  top: 3vmin;
  left: 75.5vmin;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="portrait-01">P-01</div>
  <div class="portrait-02">P-02</div>
  <div class="portrait-03">P-03</div>
  <div class="portrait-04">P-04</div>
  <div class="portrait-05">P-05</div>
  <div class="portrait-06">P-06</div>
  <div class="portrait-07">P-07</div>
  <div class="portrait-08">P-08</div>
  <div class="portrait-09">P-09</div>
  <div class="portrait-10">P-10</div>
  <div class="portrait-11">P-11</div>
  <div class="portrait-12">P-12</div>
  <div class="portrait-13">P-13</div>
  <div class="portrait-14">P-14</div>
  <div class="portrait-15">P-15</div>
  <div class="portrait-16">P-16</div>
  <div class="portrait-17">P-17</div>
  <div class="portrait-18">P-18</div>
  <div class="portrait-19">P-19</div>
  <div class="portrait-20">P-20</div>
</div>
```